# How to NOT handle some Universal Links programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, safari, appdelegate, ios-universal-links

My iOS application handles [universal links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) to redirect safari users to my app. So far everything is working great, if a user tap a link to my web site from Google my app is opening instead of my web site like this:

```
from safari https://my-web-site.com -> my-app
```

But my app doesn't implement certains features that my web site does, so I would like to programmatically reject some URLs and let my users on safari instead of redirecting him in my app, like this:

```
from safari https://my-web-site.com -> my-app
```

OR

```
from safari https://my-web-site.com?reject -> safari
```

That should by possible according to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1):

> It’s important to understand that if your app uses **openURL**: to open a universal link to your website, the link does not open in your app. In this scenario, iOS recognizes that the call originates from your app and therefore should not be handled as a universal link by your app.

Unfortunately that's not what's appending, instead of staying in safari, my user is redirected to my app for a brief moment, then redirected again to safari like this:

```
from safari https://my-web-site.com?reject -> my-app (briefly) -> safari
```

here is my code for AppDelegate.swift:

```swift
internal func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    guard let url = userActivity.webpageURL else { return false }
    guard let urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else { return false }

    let params = urlComponents.queryItems ?? []

    if params.contains(where: { $0.name == "reject" }) {
        // This line should prevent the app from opening according to Apple's documentation 
        application.open(url)
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

So anyone have an idea how I could make the rejection of an Universal link the way it's described by Apple's documentation ?

note: the rejection of an universal link need to be done programmatically by the app, according to data stored locally. So adding a path exception in the [apple-app-site-association](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/enabling_universal_links) file is **not an option** in my case :

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "XXXXXXXXX.com.my-app",
        "paths": [
          "*",
        "NOT /reject"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefix an entry in the paths array with `"NOT"` then you can explicitly prevent a match.  So in your example you could do something like

```
["NOT /settings/*", "NOT /activity/*", "/*"]
```

which would prevent paths with `/settings` or `/activity` prefixes, and then match everything else.

---

[Reference](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24981)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to do it programmatically in app. My app needs to handle or reject some URLs dynamically according to data stored locally.

Comment: I dont think it is possible programatically

Comment: @JulienBaillon this controlled by operating system, so this is the only way to proper operate with it.

Comment: Apple is pretty clear that the app should not open in my case : ["It’s important to understand that if your app uses openURL: to open a universal link to your website, the link does not open in your app."](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1)

So it should be possible...

Comment: @JulienBaillon no what you are talking about is that your app cannot call openURL and lead back to your app with some url. Your app can lead to another app or browser only. That what those words mean.

Comment: Damned... you're right, I misunderstood this sentence. Thank you for your help.

Comment: the above solution din worked for me , the link is now always pointing to website 

I codded this "paths": ["NOT /share/*", "/*"]

guys any suggestions how did u solved it @JulienBaillon

Comment: @iMinion Hello, the solution for OP was that there is no way to programmatically open app from app itself using deeplink. You can open only another app or browser.

Comment: no my question is i am not able to restrict certain urls how can i just do that to not to open app when url contains /share/ n allow rest all

Comment: @iMinion so my answer does what u are looking for. The problem is that `apple-app-site-association` file is hardly cached and you have to remove ur app from simulator/phone before u try this solution.

Comment: @iMinion full guide is here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: can we only add the content we want the universal link to open the app for.  like    "paths": ["/custom-content/"]

Comment: I also tried deleting the app and re-isnstalling it , no luck bro :(